# text() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

This is my code, having an issue with: this.element.text() - not a 
 function is the error. I'm using ES6 Classes approach. Then exporting it.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

   class WordAppear{
    constructor(element){
      this.elementValue;
      this.elementCharsSort;
      this.charValues;
      this.element = element;
      this.wordBreak();
    }
 wordBreak(){
    this.elementValue = this.element.text(); //issue here

    this.element.empty();

    this.elementCharsSort = this.elementValue.split('').sort();

    let i;
    for(i = 0; i <elementValue.length; i++){

        this.charValues = elementValue.split('')[i];

        let charSpan = $('<span>').addClass('animate-chars--is-
        hidden');

        charSpan.append(this.charValues).appendTo(element);

        charSpan.css({
            marginRight: '0.5em',
            display: 'inline-block'
        });
        setInterval(function(){
            charSpan.removeClass('animate-chars--is-hidden');
            charSpan.addClass('animate-chars--is-visible');
        }, this.elementCharsSort.indexOf(this.charValues) * 80);
      }
   }
 }

 export default WordAppear;
```

Thank you. Please help.

Comment: Then `this.element` clearly isn't a jQuery object, and has no `text()` method. Did you just try `this.element.textContent` instead ?

Comment: I'd also suggest trying `$(this.element).text()` or even just `$(this).text()`. It surely has to be a jQuery object, but it's hard to understand your case, not enough context.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: elementValue is not defined says this when i do this: 

this.elementValue = $(this.element).text();

Answer (score 0):

solved!

Class:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class WordAppear{
constructor(element){
    this.elementValue;
    this.elementCharsSort;
    this.charValues;
    this.element = $(element);
    this.wordBreak();
}

wordBreak(){
    console.log(this.element);
    this.elementValue = this.element.text();

    this.element.empty();

    this.elementCharsSort = this.elementValue.split('').sort();

    let i;
    for(i = 0; i <this.elementValue.length; i++){

        this.charValues = this.elementValue.split('')[i];

        let charSpan = $('<span>').addClass('animate-chars--is-hidden');

        charSpan.append(this.charValues).appendTo(this.element);

        charSpan.css({
            marginRight: '0.5em',
            display: 'inline-block'
        });
        setInterval(function(){
            charSpan.removeClass('animate-chars--is-hidden');
            charSpan.addClass('animate-chars--is-visible');
        }, this.elementCharsSort.indexOf(this.charValues) * 80);

       }
    }
}

export default WordAppear;
```

Class call:

```
import WordAppear from './modules/WordAppear';
import $ from 'jquery';

new WordAppear('#company-name');
```

The element itself that was being passed into the method is a jquery object, hence, the element being worked on had to be jquery element as well within the logic.

THANK YOU GUYS!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it the pure javascript mode:

```
this.elementValue = this.element.innerText; //issue here
```

Or the jQuery way:

```
this.elementValue = $(this.element).text(); //issue here
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: elementValue is not defined

says this when i do this:

this.elementValue = $(this.element).text();

Comment: Have you imported jquery? Is this element a valid DOM element?

Comment: works got it. Because I'm using jquery when passing in an element i must use jquery in the code build itself.. thank you! got it!